# C# code to search exact file name in Windows folder

Tags: .net, search, io, directory, getfiles

I have a set of files present somewhere in my Windows folder. I only know their root path and not their exact path. See below:

**List of files:**

1. Linq.doc
2. OOPs.doc

**Root path is:**

1. E:\RootFolder......\Linq.doc
2. E:\RootFolder......\OOPs.doc

I need to fetch their full path from my .Net code. So the output returned should be something like this:

**Output required:**

1. E:\RootFolder\SubFolder1\Linq.doc
2. E:\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubFolder9\OOPs.doc

I tried using following code, but it is returning incorrect results:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"E:\RootFolder");
var Filepath= Directory.GetDirectories("Linq.doc","*.doc*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Please advise what can be a better solution?

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer rather than editing the question.

Comment: GetDirectories() is not a great way to find *files*.  Surely this is a bit obvious?

Comment: @HansPassant, I had added my solution which got removed by the editor as it was in wrong place. I am using EnumerateFiles which is more efficient than GetFiles:   var results2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"E:\RootFolder", "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(p => p.Contains(sFile2));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution which is to use EnumerateFiles  with a "Where" clause. See the code below:

```
var results2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"E:\RootFolder", "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(p => p.Contains(sFile2));
```

Using EnumerateFiles  is more efficient than using GetFiles. This resolves my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles` instead of `Directory.GetDirectories`

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\RootFolder", "Linq.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have used EnumerateFiles with a "Where" clause. See my answer in the next post below